# API to custom microsoft exchange server

Tags: api, outlook, outlook-web-app

My school has OWA installed on their own servers. I've read the documentation on microsofts website, but it only targets the official outlook.

How do i go about making API calls to their OWA?

Answer (score 0):

EWS works both for the hosted (Office 365 etc.) or on-prem Exchange servers. There is no difference.